# How to delay the re-drawing of a list with JQueryUI

Tags: jquery, html, performance, jquery-ui

I am currently working with a Trello-esque layout of lists which relies on Jquery UI sortables to move elements from one list to the next. However, I'm running into serious performance issues when dragging the magnets( i.e. list items ) across several other lists.

Each time the magnet interacts with a list along the way, a placeholder is created in that list and it forces the list to re-draw.

Ideally, I'd like to implement functionality similar to the 'hover intent' plugin: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html. Something that would allow me to essentially skip over lists if the magnet is not sitting there for more than a second.

Unfortunately, I've yet to successfully implement functionality which mimics the hover intent idea. Any suggestions or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Easiest thing to try is the droppable option `tolerance: "fit"`, which won't impose a delay but will tighten the tolerance such that the draggable is much less likely to trigger an intermediate droppable match. This will of course make it more difficult to drop on the intended target but that's something you would have to live with. Best thing to do is give it a try and see if it improves matters.